# Trailing slash (duplicate) added on redirect (javascript/react)

Tags: javascript

For a few reasons I am having to redirect my page and upon this event, a double slash is added to my url being left with something like this:

`https://www.mydomain.or//images/logo.gif`

Instead of:

`https://www.mydomain.or/images/logo.gif`

How can I ensure that the double training slash after my domain is not added?

Comment: You can use a str replace on '//'. However to prevent it happening we don't have enough info. Probably you have to lose a / in the beginning of your redirect url.

Comment: thanks @Wimanicesir I have used:
function someFunction(site) {
        return site.replace(/\/$/, ''));
 }
but unfortunately the problem persists. Do I have to add something to the function that specifies the "replacement" is on redirect?

Comment: If your domain base url is constant you can just remove extra / from url string at that index where it is occuring everytime.